# 500 Server Error after deployment Django in App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy a Django website for sharing notes using app engine.

Everything works fine until I try to upload file to my database, either through app interface or admin interface, as it results in `500 Server error`.

As I have gone through similar questions, I know that this error is not caused by the app engine, but I am really confused because it works fine locally.

I was able to upload file to database connecting it through cloud proxy.

I tried to check log and debug but didn't give any clue.

Further info:
when deployed setting setting DEBUG=True it shows this error while uploading ...

```
[Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/srv/media/storage/hall_ETTBXhS.jpeg'
```

Additional info : I'm using django 3.0.3

#### Here is my `views.py` :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models  import notes
from .forms import upload
import datetime

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    context={}
    context["dataset"] = notes.objects.all()
    return render(request, "noteitdown/home.html", context)

def upload_view(request):
    context = {}
    date = datetime.date.today()
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        form = upload(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            entry = notes(author_name=data["author_name"], date_of_pub=date, department=data["department"], file=data["file"])
            entry.save()
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    form = upload()
    context["form"] = form
    return render(request, "noteitdown/upload.html", context)

def about(request):
    return render(request, "noteitdown/about.html")
```

#### my `Models.py` :

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class notes(models.Model):
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date_of_pub = models.DateField()
    department = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="storage/")
```

#### and here my `settings.py` :

```
"""
Django settings for website project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See 

    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

    # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
    SECRET_KEY = '[SECRET_KEY]'

    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    DEBUG = False

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]


    # Application definition

    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'noteitdown.apps.NoteitdownConfig',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ]

    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'website.urls'

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': ['noteitdown/templates'],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'website.wsgi.application'


    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases
    import pymysql
    pymysql.version_info = (1, 3, 13, "final", 0)
    pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

    if os.getenv('GAE_APPLICATION', None):
        # Running on production App Engine, so connect to Google Cloud SQL using
        # the unix socket at /cloudsql/<your-cloudsql-connection string>
        DATABASES = {
            'default': {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
                'HOST': '/cloudsql/[SQL_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]',
                'USER': '[USER]',
                'PASSWORD': '[PASSWORD]',
                'NAME': 'website_db',
            }
        }
    else:
        DATABASES = {
            'default': {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
                'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
                'PORT': '3306',
                'NAME': 'website_db',
                'USER': '[USER]',
                'PASSWORD': '[PASSWORD]',
            }
        }
    # Password validation
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

    AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
        },
    ]


    # Internationalization
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

    TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

    USE_I18N = True

    USE_L10N = True

    USE_TZ = True


    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/')
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media/')

    try:
      import googleclouddebugger
      googleclouddebugger.enable()
    except ImportError:
  pass
```

#### App Engine log :

```
2020-05-18 02:34:36.192 IST GET 200 1.07 KiB 12 ms Chrome 81 /noteitdown/upload
2020-05-18 02:35:13.219 IST POST 500 337 B 3.2 s Chrome 81 /noteitdown/upload
```

#### Local django log :

```
[17/May/2020 20:20:43] "POST /noteitdown/upload HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[17/May/2020 20:20:43] "GET /noteitdown/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2158
```

Comment: Turn on debugging should give you more information, but don't forget to turn it off.

Comment: A 5xx code means that there was a server error, which leads me to believe that you will find a stacktrace within GAE's logs with the exception that triggered the 500 code. Once you find it share it with us so we can help you troubleshoot further.

Comment: thanks @KrerkkiatChusap took your advise & turned on debugging... it turns out to be showing this error... 

[Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/srv/media/storage/hall_ETTBXhS.jpeg'

can u help me fix it...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the error you are facing is because you are writing a file into an instance's file system. According to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-temp-files) you can only write temporary files to the directory `/tmp`. Bear in mind that doing that would use RAM memory (not storage) and it would be only available on the instance that created the file.

If you intend to persist files you should [use Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-cloud-storage).

Comment: @baarathsrinivasan If you think this answer solves your problem or explains why you have it, you should accept it. This is in order to make the solution reach more people who are facing/will face the same problem.

Comment: yeah sure @Ajordat. i had this error because i was trying to upload files to staging bucket of app engine . So i used django-storage ( https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html ) to save uploaded files to separate bucket. now it is working fine.

Comment: @baarathsrinivasan Trying to write to GAE's bucket triggers a "Read-only file system" error? It looks like a misleading message from Python. Still, as you have seen, an App cannot interact with [GAE's default bucket](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-cloud-storage#default_bucket).